# Trouble with 'if' statement in a script

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, while-loop, sh

I have a list file with many different columns, and want to know whenever the next value in the third column is equal to the current value on third column. My problem is, those values are directories, looking like this:

```
/media/user/DATA/Folder1/File1.extension
/media/user/DATA/Folder1/File1.extension
/media/user/DATA/Folder1/File2.extension
/media/user/DATA/Folder1/File2.extension
/media/user/DATA/Folder2/File3.extension
/media/user/DATA/Folder2/File4.extension
/media/user/DATA/Folder2/File5.extension
/media/user/DATA/Folder3/File6.extension
/media/user/DATA/Folder4/File6.extension
```

I have files with the same name in the same folder (which should be considered as an equal value), same name in different folders (must be recognized as different values) and same folder but different names (different values).

What I had been trying to do was to sort them all (with sort -k 3,3), then make a fourth column saying whether the next value is the same as the one in the column or not, looking something like this:

```
/media/user/DATA/Folder1/File1.extension Y
/media/user/DATA/Folder1/File1.extension N
/media/user/DATA/Folder1/File2.extension Y
/media/user/DATA/Folder1/File2.extension N
/media/user/DATA/Folder2/File3.extension N
/media/user/DATA/Folder2/File4.extension N
/media/user/DATA/Folder2/File5.extension N
/media/user/DATA/Folder3/File6.extension N
/media/user/DATA/Folder4/File6.extension N
```

I came up with this code to do that, but it keeps showing errors when comparing R1 with LastR1, which I think may be due to the "/" in the strings...

```
echo "N" > LastR1.kp
sort -k3,3 list > list.tmp
mv list list.backup
mv list.tmp list

while read T1 T2 R1; do
    LastR1=`cat LastR1.kp`
    if [ $R1 == $LastR1 ]
    then
        KeepR1="Y"
    else
        KeepR1="N"
    fi
    echo "$KeepR1" > CKeep.kp
    cat KeepList.kp CKeep.kp > KeepList.kp
done
sed -i -e 1,2d KeepList
join list KeepList > list.tmp
mv list.tmp list
```

So, what I would have at the end, would be my original file, with a fourth column with either Y (for 'next row has the same value in 3rd column) or N (for 'different value on the next row'). 
I can't seem to find the reason why my if statement doesn't work - and, even though I think this approach could do what I need, I'm definitely open to different approaches

Comment: What is the input to your `while read` loop?

Comment: What error are you getting? `==` inside `[ ... ]` is supported by some shells, but not all.

Comment: The input was a list file, with the different directories, forgot to put it here somehow, but it is the .sh file. I was using a test with A/A, A/B. A/C, B/A for the Directories, and got this error message

./testes.sh: 7: [: A/A: unexpected operator
./testes.sh: 7: [: A/B: unexpected operator
./testes.sh: 7: [: A/B: unexpected operator
./testes.sh: 7: [: A/C: unexpected operator
./testes.sh: 7: [: B/A: unexpected operator

Which is why I thought the "/" was the problem (reading as "division")

Managed to make it work now, with the "[[ ]]" and "#!/usr/bin/env bash", thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are using `bash` or `sh`.  Add the shebang line on top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

and change the `if` condition to use `[[ ]]`:

```
if [[ $R1 == $LastR1 ]]
```

I hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: I'm using sh, not sure why I even added bash there, sorry :s

Comment: That worked, thanks. Also had to change my `join` function, if anyone happens to run into a similar problem, using a paste function instead (paste file1 file2). Thanks!